# Why does my app never get terminated in background mode?

Tags: ios, swift, background, uikit

I realised that my app can stay in background mode for a whole night, which leads to weird issue of the UI appearance style when I reopen it.

So the situation is that I update my UI by override this function every time when a user has changed their system appearance mode, which is working well when the app is being active.

```swift
func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
     super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
     self.updateUI()
}
```

However, every overnight, my app is not terminated by the operation system, and when I reopen it in the morning, there are only few UI elements are updated, and the traitCollectionDidChange is not called, at this time, I think my app should already be killed for staying in background for that long time, and it will working fine when a user reopen it to refresh the UI, but it wasn't.

How can I manually terminate my app when it's being inactive for a specific time?

Comment: you shouldn't do this, instead use `applicationDidBecomeActive` event, and update your UI when app returns to be active.

Comment: You should report this as a bug. If you app never gets terminated there might be a bigger issue

Comment: Are you running your app under Xcode. If so, it wont be terminated.  
Also, an app is typically only terminated when some other app needs resources, such as memory, so if your phone is just sitting there overnight I wouldn't expect your app to be terminated. Finally you shouldn't need to react manually to an appearance mode trait change. Simply use dynamic colours and let the system handle it for you.